# Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type - Firebase Error

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

**its firebase Error I cant get it please Help me to solve and tell me the reason why its happens.
sorry For english and try to solve it**

```
    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.kunalgharate.weedon, PID: 16793
              com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.kunalgharate.weedon.Friends
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zg.zzb(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zg.zza(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source)
                  at com.firebase.ui.database.ClassSnapshotParser.parseSnapshot(ClassSnapshotParser.java:22)
                  at com.firebase.ui.database.ObservableSnapshotArray.getObject(ObservableSnapshotArray.java:160)
                  at com.firebase.ui.database.CachingObservableSnapshotArray.getObject(CachingObservableSnapshotArray.java:40)
                  at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.getItem(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:180)
                  at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.onBindViewHolder(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:217)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6482)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6515)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5458)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5724)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5563)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5559)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2229)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1556)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1516)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:608)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3693)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3410)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.consumePendingUpdateOperations(RecyclerView.java:1710)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$1.run(RecyclerView.java:346)
                  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:871)
                  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:683)
                  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:616)
                  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:857)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
```

Application terminated.

Activity Main

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    RecyclerView mSubsList;
    DatabaseReference mFriendsDatabase;
    DatabaseReference mUsersDatabase;
    private String mCurrent_user_id;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.main_page_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
         getSupportActionBar().setTitle("WeedON");
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mCurrent_user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        mSubsList =findViewById(R.id.subscribes_list);
        mSubsList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mSubsList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


        mFriendsDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("subscribers").child(mCurrent_user_id);
        mFriendsDatabase.keepSynced(true);
        mUsersDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
        mUsersDatabase.keepSynced(true);




    }

    private void signOut() {
        mAuth.signOut();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Friends,MainViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Friends,MainViewHolder>(


                Friends.class,
                R.layout.single_service_layout,
                MainViewHolder.class,
                mFriendsDatabase
                )
        {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(MainViewHolder viewHolder, Friends model, int position) {



            }
        };

       mSubsList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
        }





    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);

        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        if(item.getItemId() == R.id.main_logout_btn){

          //  mUserRef.child("online").setValue(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);

            signOut();
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
         //   sendToStart();

        }

        if(item.getItemId() == R.id.main_settings_btn){

            Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class);
            startActivity(settingsIntent);

        }

        if(item.getItemId() == R.id.main_all_btn){

            Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AllServicesActivity.class);
            startActivity(settingsIntent);

        }

        return true;
    }

    public static class MainViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        View mView;

        public MainViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mView =itemView;
        }


    }



}
```

Database Screenshot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51WNU.png)

its Not showing layout Error or code Error what should i do ?

Answer (score 1):

By looking at your database I can see that your mFriendsDatabase DatabseReference points to some 'String' Values and you are telling your firebaseRecyclerAdapter that those are of type 'Friends,that is why the exception is thrown.Most probably your are doing a mistake while saving the value to database,instead of saving a Friends object you are saving some String value.But if that's not the case you can change your firebaseRecyclerAdapter to this...

```
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<String,MainViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<String,MainViewHolder>(


            String.class,
            R.layout.single_service_layout,
            MainViewHolder.class,
            mFriendsDatabase
            )
    {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(MainViewHolder viewHolder, String mString, int position) {
          Log.d("TAG",mString);
        }
    };

   mSubsList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

To display those messages, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference uidRef = rootRef.child("subscribers").child(mCurrent_user_id);
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String message = ds.getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("TAG", message);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
uidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```